# Watij Replacement

Tags: java, automation, acceptance-testing, automated-tests, watij

Does anyone know of a good replacement to Watij which will allow automated tests to be written in Java?  It looks like the Watij library isn't being developed anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at this list.  I'm not sure if any is a direct replacement and works exactly like Watij, but it might give you some other options:

http://java-source.net/open-source/web-testing-tools

And you might find some options might be better than before (e.g. Selenium)

Comment: I notice that Selenium now has a Java adapter.  Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is a really good option.

Answer (score 0):

On their website you can see that they have come up with replacement as "webspec "framework. It is easier to use than watij.